# For $\lambda \lt \operatorname{cof}( \kappa)$ is it true that $\kappa^{\lambda}=\kappa$?

Tags: set-theory, cardinals

Let $\lambda$ and $\kappa$ be cardinals. I think the statement

$0 \lt \lambda \lt \operatorname{cof} \kappa \Rightarrow \kappa^{\lambda}=\kappa$

is true in ZFC, but not sure.

Edit: The statement is false in general, as Keith show with the case $\aleph_{0} < \operatorname{cof}(\aleph_{1})$ but $\aleph_{1}=\aleph_{1}^{\aleph_{0}}$  is equivalent to the continuum hypothesis, what is know to be independet of ZFC (to see this remember $2^{\aleph_{0}}\leq \aleph_{1}^{\aleph_{0}}$)

There are isteresting situations where the statement is true, as $\lambda$ finite or $\kappa= \beth_{\beta}$ for $\beta$ a limit ordinal.

This two cases are all the cases?

For the ones who are learning these things, like me: $\beth$ is a cardinal function defined as
$\beth_{0}=\aleph_{0}$
$\beth_{\beta}=\displaystyle\bigcup_{\alpha< \beta}2^{\beth_{\alpha}}$

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Consider the case $\kappa = \aleph_1$ and $\lambda = \aleph_0$.

Comment: Thanks @KeithKearnes

Comment: It’s not necessarily true that $\aleph_1<\aleph_1^{\aleph_0}.$ This is equivalent to saying the continuum hypothesis is false.